# getpass isn't working in jupyter notebook (python 3.6, Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, getpass

I recently updated from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.  getpass was working with jupyter in ubuntu 16.04.  However, since the upgrade it has ceased to work.

Whenever I enter getpass.getpass in a jupyter notebook, the box will show up where you can enter a password.  But when I hit enter, the cell will not actually run.  Instead I can just keep editing the inputed password in the box as long as I want. Its as if the enter key isn't being recognized at all.

I tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda in case the update had broken something; however, the error is still persisting. I've tried importing getpass in both python and ipython in the terminal, and it works normally in both of those.  It's only in jupyter where I get the unusual behavior.

Does anyone have any idea of how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: same issue with python 3.6; jupyter-notebook 5.7.2... and just upgraded to 5.7.4: the problem remains.

Comment: It appears that this is actually related to firefox (see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4409).   I tried replicating the issue with chrome, and getpass worked fine.